# eclipse plugin handler to invoke jax-ws webservice

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jax-ws

i have a jax-ws "hello world service" running in my tomcat.i am working on designing a  eclipse plugin to invoke the web service.could anyone please guide me doing so.

Answer (score 0):

you could start reading [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html) tutorial: it's a comprehensive tutorial about developing eclipse based RCP and plug-ins.

the simplest thing you could do is writing a vewi (chap 7 in the tutorial) and whiring the data displayed to the webservice output.